# Forum/s, Topics, Discussions and Posts

Tags: internet, syntactic-analysis

There are many internet forums out there and I am wondering which would be the most correct way to structure one's own forum.
For example, many forums are stated as "Forums" (even more use the singular "Forum" form or "Board"), then coming up with "Categories", "Discussions" or "Topics" and finally "Posts" or "Comments".

I would like to know what you would prefer and if you would make some distinction between some forms of "Forums" when naming their structure.

Comment: Please see [faq] re asking "practical, answerable questions".  The question seems unclear to me, and some may term it non-constructive or will note that the [faq] claims that "naming" is "out of scope for this site"

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. It wasn't my intention to have it "named", I was wondering what is the correct "term" or "vocable" for a forum structure. :)

Comment: Your question and comment have me a bit confused. Are you looking for the word _nomenclature_? Or are you seeking help in _defining_ a nomenclature for a discussion board?

Comment: That's definitely what I intended to ask. To correctly define a nomenclature for a discussion board! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical and minimalistic structure for a discussion board is:

Forum -> Thread -> Post

Then, you can group forums in categories and forums may contain subforums.

But, it greatly depends on the workflow of the system. In order to get a feeling of the terminology used, it'd be better to have a look at the history of such systems (e.g. Bulletin Board systems) and the concept of ancient agoras/forums.

But, in order not to start over-describing the whole concept, it's all about practicality and distinguishing online and offline discussions/concepts. So, offline, you have discussions on topics, and online you have conversation threads containing posts (like posts in a real bulletin board).

A comment provides additional information/input on something else, whereas a post provides a complete answer.

**edit:**

Imagine someone asking if "Twitter's 'tweets' are **different** from Facebook's 'posts' and StackExhange's 'answers'". It wouldn't really be relevant to ask if 'tweet' is a valid word, right? It's their system, they may call their 'units of dialog' whatever they want ;). I could tell someone that I "read their comment on tweeter", and they would have every right to look at me strange but they'd nevertheless be able to understand what I meant.